# Create MySQL DB from Command Line

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

I am trying to create a batch file to create a MySQL Database. So far, none of the information I am finding is working. Just for testing, this is what I am trying...

```
C:\>mysql -uroot -ppassword < CREATE DATABASE testdb;
C:\>mysql -uroot -ppassword mysql < CREATE DATABASE testdb;
```

No matter how I put it, I keep getting the error "The system cannot find the file specified". If I just put...

```
C:\>mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

It logs into the MySQL prompt fine. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I agree with the other posters, it's much better to put the schema into a file.  However, here's how you can do it on the command line:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -e "CREATE DATABASE testdb"
```

Answer (score 7):

acess as root user :

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it asks for password..enter your password

then
run the create command like this:

```
mysql> create database database_name;
```

Answer (score 6):

It's better to write your MySQL inside a file and then import that file. That way, when you need to run it again (reinstalling or migrating) you have a record of the MySQL to run. The code I use for a file like this is as follows, which destroys anything that's already there, and then creates the database and assigns a dedicated user.

```
# uninstall if anything's already there
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%';
DROP USER 'username'@'%';
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `tablename`;

# create the user
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `tablename`;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `tablename` . * TO 'username'@'%';
```

Comment: That is perfect except I can't put it in a file. The batch script is written in our web panel, then executed on the relevant machine. This is the reason I am actually writing out the script rather than creating an .sql file and executing it. I was able to get the DB created with "mysqladmin -uroot -ppass CREATE testdb" but as far as creating users and assigning permissions, its not working too well.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting your sql into a text file, like 'createDb.sql' and then run:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword < createDb.sql;
```

Comment: Are you sure it needs a semi-colon on the end?

Comment: @JW. no it doesn't. But it does no harm as shell eats it up.